# Set messages pattern in Log4J

Tags: java, log4j2, log4j

I have this Log4J configuration which generates messages into log file:

```
log = Logger.getLogger(LogMessages.class.getName());
        BasicConfigurator.configure();  // Basic configuration for Log4J 1.x

        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
        //configure the appender
        String PATTERN = "%d{DATE} [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
        console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN));
        console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
        console.activateOptions();
        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

        DailyRollingFileAppender fa = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("log" + File.separator + "messages.log");
        fa.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();

        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa); //repeat with all other desired appenders
```

This is the generated output:

```
2013-12-26 10:19:27,501 WARN  [LogMessages] test_message
```

I would like to generate message like this:

```
2013-12-26 10:19:27 WARN test_message
```

How I can remove [LogMessages] from the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file logging, change the `setLayout` invocation to:

```
fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p %m%n"));
```

For the console logging also, use the same pattern:

```
String PATTERN = "%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p %m%n";
```

Comment: Into the console I get this output: `0 [FelixStartLevel] WARN org.test.ts.impl.LogMessages  - test_messages`. Into the log file I get this message: `2013-12-26 11:10:19,428 WARN  test_messages`. How I can get only `2013-12-26 11:10:19 WARN  test_messages`?

Comment: I get this into the log file: `26/12/2013 11:45:55 WARN  test____scs` How I can remove WARN?

Comment: Get rid of %-5p in this case.

Comment: Yes this solves the problem for text file logging. Into the console I get this output `0 [FelixStartLevel] WARN org.test.ts.impl.LogMessages  - test____scs`. Hwo I can change it to look like the text file format?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Try using the same pattern string for your console appender as well, I've updated my answer

Comment: I get this output: `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO org.test.ts.impl.LogMessages  - test____scs
26/12/2013 12:26:09 test____scs` Maybe it's configuration issue?

Comment: This line is the problem: `log = Logger.getLogger(LogMessages.class.getName());` This code generates the line `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO org.test.ts.impl.LogMessages - test____scs`. How I can edit the code so I won't get anything on the console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43912/discussion-between-aquaraga-and-peter-penzov)

Comment: I'm unable to move this to chat. Anyways, is the issue that you're now getting 2 lines on the console (1 wrong, and the other one proper)? I believe this has to do something with the log4j additivity flag, but unsure how this can be set programatically.

Comment: Yes I want to remove this from the console output: `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO org.test.ts.impl.LogMessages - test____scs `. This generated from the code: `log = Logger.getLogger(LogMessages.class.getName());` Is there any way to disable this code?

Comment: here is your pattern, "WARN removed": http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25d%7Bdd%2FMM%2Fyyyy+HH%3Amm%3Ass%7D+%25m%25n